# Selenium sometimes not showing all elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all products in the website, in the website it's just load 20 products you have to scroll down to load more products, in following code I have a way to scroll down to load the more products but the problem is I tried to run the code 5 times only 2 times the code scraped all the elements, is there any solutions to the problem?

**Code**

```
products_details = []
market_page = "https://shop.tamimimarkets.com"
website = "https://shop.tamimimarkets.com/category/fresh"
def Find_all_products(URL):
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/chromeDriver', options=options)
    driver.get(URL)
    time.sleep(3)
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight - 1300);")
    # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(3)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
    
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
    product = soup.find_all("a",{'class':'yDbmR'})
    for p in product:
        product_URL = market_page + p.attrs['href']
        products_details.append(product_URL)

for _ in range(5):
   Find_all_products(website)
   print(len(products_details))
   products_details.clear()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1136
2721
2721
498
1398
```

Comment: The inconsistency your experiencing might be due to the variable load time of the website's html. Try testing this by waiting like 10 or more seconds after each scroll. If the results become consistent, this would suggest that it is the html-load time that is causing the inconsistency. You can use the selenium `WebDriverWait` class to set explicit wait times.

Comment: Also, add the `import` statements so that its easier for people to test your code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to use their Ajax API directly (using `requests`):

```py
import requests

url = 'https://website-api.ecom-dev.tamimimarkets.com/api/product?category=fresh&layoutType=GRID&loadMoreType=INFINITE&sorting=NEW_LAST&page={page}'

for page in range(1, 3):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    data = requests.get(url.format(page=page)).json()
    for p in data['data']['product']:
        for v in p['variants']:
            name = v['fullName']
            mrp = v['storeSpecificData'][-1]['mrp']
            discount = v['storeSpecificData'][-1]['discount']
            vat = v['storeSpecificData'][-1]['tax']['VAT']
            print(f'{name:<50} {mrp:<10} {discount:<10} {vat:<10}')
```

Prints:

```
Shredded Mozzarella Cheese - 1Kg                   49.95      0          15        
Shredded Mozzarella Cheese - 200G                  11.95      0          15        
Shredded Mozzarella Cheese - 200G                  10.95      0          15        
Shredded Mozzarella Cheese - 450G                  23.75      0          15        
Shredded Mozzarella Cheese - 900G                  42.95      15         15        
Labneh Turkish Recipe - 400G                       14.25      0          15        
Labneh Turkish Recipe - 650G                       25         10.05      15        
Labneh Turkish Recipe - 180G                       8.5        0          15        
Smoked Salmon Scottish -  100G                     39.95      0          15        
Smoked Salmon Scottish -  200G                     65.95      0          15        
Cheese Slices Burger - 200G                        9.5        0          15        
Cheese Slices Burger - 400G                        17.25      5.3        15        
Cheese Slices Burger - 4×200G                      30.25      0          15        

...and so on.
```